# [Pentaho][Using Shell script][CMD] insert count line and table name into txt file

Tags: shell, cmd, pentaho-spoon

I am trying to writing script by using shell scripting in pentaho.

First,file name "test_viewpayment4.txt". 
I have to count the line, the correct output is 100(which not include the header), and I have to get the file name also. After that,creates the txt file which include count line and file name as picture below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/afrGg.png

Here is my code in Pentaho

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYuWw.png

```
CMD.EXE /C 
call cd /d d:\test
call set file=test_viewpayment4.txt
call Type d:\test\test_viewpayment4.txt | more +2 | find /V /C "~~~" > d:\test\Result5.txt
call echo %file% >> d:\test\Result5.txt
```

Here is the result in Result5.txt

```
100
test_viewpayment4.txt
```

However,the data is not in the same line.
Any help or pointing the right direction will be really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a `for` loop to get a command's output to a variable:

```
for /f %%a in ('more +2 "d:\test\test_viewpayment4.txt" ^|find /v /c ""') do set lines=%%a
```

then just echo all in one command:

```
>> d:\test\Result5.txt echo %file% %lines%
```

(Note: none of the `call` commands is necessary in batch; also `cmd /c` is useless. Dismiss them, except Pentaho (which I don't know) needs them)